# How to pass Gitlab CI/CD variables with a newline to "oc process"?

Tags: openshift, gitlab-ci

In a Gitlab project I have several CI/CD variables with line breaks (newlines) in them. I need to pass these variables to an "oc process" call (Openshift client), like this:

```
oc process -f sometemplate.yml -v TEMPLATE_PARAM=$VAR_WITH_NEWLINE
```

When using a variable with newlines, I get the error message "Error: bad flag syntax". I tried escaping the newlines with \n but that didn't work either.

I was not able to find any post about this problem on Google. Does anybody know how to accomplish this? Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your template and an example of the desired processing result? If you want the content of the variable to be escaped you could just put your env-var into quotes: `... TEMPLATE_PARAM="$VAR_WITH_NEWLINE"`

Comment: Of course it had to be something that simple ;-) Adding the double-quotes did the trick. @fab, if you turn your comment into an official answer, I'll check it off so you get the credit for it.

Comment: I have found myself in that situation many times... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To escape the content of the environment variable correctly, putting it into quotes `"..."` is sufficient:

```
oc process -f sometemplate.yml -v TEMPLATE_PARAM="$VAR_WITH_NEWLINE"
```